# how to let web application use the purchased domain name through ROUTE 53 in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

1. I have purchased a domain name through ROUTE 53.
   2) I have created a EC2 instance and put my web application inside it that is supposed to be hosted.
   3) I have configured the Gunicorn and nginx as my WSGI and web server.

How to use the purchased domain name to integrate with my application to see over the internet. I have seen many documents post on stackoverflow, and youtube videos. But I am not able to get the clear picture of what am suppose to do next.

I get that once the domain is registered I have 4 ns records generated inside the ROUTE 53. But where to use them? how to configure them.

It be helpful if somebody can give me exact steps to perform the tasks.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Route53 is similar to other DNS servers with extra features, in your case, you will need to assign your ec2 instance a public IP address and to be safe an Elastic IP to avoid IP change on reboot, then you need to grab this public IP and assign it to your domain root A record and www CNAME record to point to that domain

Answer (score 2):

> I get that once the domain is registered I have 4 ns records generated
> inside the ROUTE 53. But where to use them? how to configure them.

Normally it's not required but it's helpful to control your DNS configuration from route 53 instead of the DNS registrar.

- Create [Hosted zone](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/migrate-dns-domain-inactive.html) in route 53, for example if your domain name is `example.com` then create  Hosted zone in route with name `example.com`, it will generate name server record.
- Open newly created hosted zone and copy Name server `(NS)` record and replace the `NS` record in your DNS setting.

> When you create a hosted zone, **Route 53 automatically creates a name server (NS) record and a start of authority (SOA) record for the zone**. The NS record identifies the four name servers that Route 53 associated with your hosted zone. To make Route 53 the DNS service for your domain, you update the registration for the domain to use these four name servers.

[image]

Add these record in DNS Name server, for example the below one is used for Godaddy

[image]
[migrating-a-domain-to-amazon-route53](https://lobster1234.github.io/2017/05/10/migrating-a-domain-to-amazon-route53/)

Comment: Ok, let me try to work with it, will keep you posted